# Printing space between strings when using strcat() function

Tags: c, string, strcat

How to print a space between two strings using strcat() function in c language?

Comment: Watch out not to run into Shlemiel while you're at it!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
strcat(string1, " ");
strcat(string1, string2);
```

or, just in one line.

```
strcat(strcat(string1, " "),string2)
```

Both the snippets are actually same!

Comment: Except the second is fairly bad practice and pretty messy.